# How to maintain indentation for commented out code?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, comments, indentation

I'm having a problem with eclipse not formatting comments the way I want. When I comment out code I want the alignment maintained but I'm having difficulty getting this to work.

Wanted:

```
        if (isTrue) {
            // get it done
            doIt();
//      } else {
//          log("Take note of this");
        }
```

Formatted result:

```
        if (isTrue) {
            // get it done
            doIt();
// } else {
// log("Take note of this");
        }
```

Comment: I personally never found a solution to that aside from using plugins for eclipse. I believe part of the reason is that it would mess with indenting the rest properly since commented code doesn't have to be "safe" for the layout/compiler

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + 7 seem to work in my eclipse and formats ok

I've also heard for commenting out blocks its ctrl + shift + /

Comment: I'm only interested in using line comments. My trouble is with how they get formatted rather than how to comment out code

Comment: You say "When I comment out code I want the alignment maintained but I'm having difficulty getting this to work" . As my answer says, highlight the line and try 'ctrl+ 7' or 'ctrl + shift + / ' or 'ctrl + / ' . it maintains formatting

Comment: That depends on your code formatter's settings. One of my save actions is to format source code